# Cannot Start Oracle Database after Shutdown

Tags: oracle, oracle-11g-r2, startup

I have install oracle 11.2.0.4 with oracle asm on oracle linux 6.4 and it work correctly .
After shutdown abort , i can not start database at all .
can any one help me ?

```
SQL*Plus: Release 11.2.0.4.0 Production on Sun Sep 6 14:14:30 2015


Copyright (c) 1982, 2013, Oracle.  All rights reserved.


Enter user-name: sys as sysdba
Enter password:
Connected to an idle instance.


SQL> startup
ORA-27137: unable to allocate large pages to create a shared memory segment
Linux-x86_64 Error: 1: Operation not permitted
Additional information: 201326592
Additional information: 1
SQL>


--------------------------------------------
[grid@localhost ~]$ asmcmd
ASMCMD> startup
ORA-01081: cannot start already-running ORACLE - shut it down first
-------------------------------------------
[root@localhost ~]#  grep Huge /proc/meminfo
AnonHugePages:    100352 kB
HugePages_Total:       0
HugePages_Free:        0
HugePages_Rsvd:        0
HugePages_Surp:        0
Hugepagesize:       2048 kB
```

Comment: please do a `ps -fe|grep pmon` and show us the output

Comment: also do `echo $ORACLE_SID, $ORACLE_HOME` in the environment where you opened sqlplus and asmcmd to start the database

Comment: oracle_sid is orcl and the output of asmcmd and startup in my question

Comment: I don't understand "and the output of asmcmd and startup in my question"

Comment: please provide the output of the ps command (see one of the comments above)

Answer (score 1):

```
$ oerr ora 27137
27137, 00000, "unable to allocate large pages to create a shared memory segment"
// *Cause: Parameter USE_LARGE_PAGES set to only, but large pages were not
//         configured properly
// *Action: Check alert file for more information
```

Your output shows hugepages were not configured, but the database is configured to use only large pages (`use_large_pages=only`), hence it can not start.

Configure the required amount of pages by setting the `vm.nr_hugepages` in `/etc/sysctl.conf`, the appropriate `memlock` limit in `/etc/security/limits.conf`, then reboot and start the database.

[Configuring HugePages on Linux](http://docs.oracle.com/cd/E11882_01/server.112/e10839/appi_vlm.htm#UNXAR396)

If you do not need hugepages, simply edit the parameter file of the database, and unset the `use_large_pages` parameter.